# $\frac{\pi}2 < \sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2} < \frac{3\pi}4 $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

**Prove that:**

$\frac{\pi}2 < \sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2} < \frac{3\pi}4 $

**What I've tried:**

I solved the improper integral:  $\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \lim_{b\to \infty} \arctan b -\arctan 0 = \frac{\pi}2 $.

Now, everything in the sum (and in the integral) is positive so the sum must be lower than the integral (it has more members), so the claim is wrong (originally it was a "Prove/Disprove" problem...). However, if we only add the first 3 members we get 1.7 which is bigger than $\frac{\pi}2 $.
Also, I checked with wolfram and the sum is somewhere around 2 so the claim is true. I have no idea how to prove it.

Someone suggested I would read Basel's problem ,in which the integral is also smaller than the sum (starting from 1) but it led me nowhere and I don't think that this kind of complex solution is needed here.

Comment: I don't understand what the following means, and if anything, it sounds like incorrect logic: "Now, everything in the sum (and in the integral) is positive so the sum must be lower than the integral (it has more members),"

Comment: the function (or series) is positive for every x from 0 to infinity. so the Sum is the sum of positive numbers and the integral is also the sum of positive integers. Therfore, I think that because the integral contains both natural numbers and unnatural numbers its result has to be bigger. (Maybe, you can explain to me why its a wrong assumption...)

Comment: Sure, both the sum and the integral include components coming from natural numbers. But in the sum, these components are counted with weight $1$. And in the integral, they are counted with weight the infinitesimally small $dx$. So you cannot do this direct comparison.

Instead, draw a picture of the integral area under the curve. Then overlay with boxes that are one unit wide, starting with a leftmost box's left side at $x=0$. The sum of these box areas is the value of your sum. And the picture shows that in fact $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}>\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Note what is important is that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is a positive _decreasing_ function.

Comment: ok, I get it now. Thanks. Now I need to understand the upper bound...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key result to use is that if $f(x)$ is a continuous strictly decreasing function, then $f(n+1) < \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)\,dx < f(n)$.

If we take the sum over all values of $n$ starting at $n=0$ using the right inequality, we get that $$\frac{\pi}{2} = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} < \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2},$$

and if we sum over all values of $n$ starting at $n=1$ and use the left inequality, we get
$$  \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2} < \int_{1}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}  = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
We then get the desired inequality as follows:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2} < \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} < \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{4}.$$ (This elaboration is necessary since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is increasing on $[-1,0]$, as noted in comments.)

Comment: from x=-1 to 0 the function in not strictly decreasing...

Comment: @NoamMansur you are quite correct! I wonder if whoever wrote the question noticed this detail.  I think I have filled in the gap appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

An advanced approach using zeta function values $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(4)$ to get even better bounds.

For $n>1$, $$\frac{1}{1+n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac1{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}-\frac{1}{n^8}+...$$

So $$\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^4}<\frac{1}{n^2+1}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

So:

$$\frac{3}{2}+\left(\zeta(2)-\zeta(4)-\left(\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^4}\right)\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n^2} -\frac{1}{n^4}\right)<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}  < \frac{1}{2} + \zeta(2)$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{2}+\zeta(2)=\frac 12+\frac{\pi^2}{6} <\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

And:

$$\frac{21}{16}+\zeta(2)-\zeta(4) = \frac{21}{16} + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi^4}{90}>\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: since I never encountered zeta function until this moment I suspect there is a more simple solution. (This question was given to me as part of a calculus exam...)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put "advanced" and "zeta" at th beginning. I realize this is not the likely answer a homework problem is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one could be very silly and note that the sum in question has a well-known exact value:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{1+n^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{coth}{\pi} + \frac12 $$

Now

$$\operatorname{coth}{\pi} = \frac{1+e^{-2 \pi}}{1-e^{-2 \pi}} \approx 1+2 e^{-2 \pi} \approx 1$$

It is not hard to show that the inequality is true from this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's interesting to see why we have the closed form $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\coth\left(\pi\right)+\frac{1}{2}
 $$ and a way is to use this well known result from complex analysis: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(n\right)=-\pi\sum_{k=1}^{m}\textrm{Res}\left(f\left(z\right)\cot\left(\pi z\right),a_{k}\right)
 $$ where $a_{k}
 $ are all poles of $f\left(z\right)
 $. In this case the poles are $\pm i
 $, so, observing that also holds $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}}=2\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}}-1
 $$ we have $$ \sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}}=\frac{\pi\coth\left(\pi\right)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}
 $$ and it's easily to see that, as Ron Gordon showed, this number is between $\pi/2
 $ and $3\pi/4
 $.

Answer (score 0):

Since for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{1+n^2} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-x}\,dx $$
it follows that 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+n^2} = 1 + \int_{0}^{+\infty}w(x) e^{-x}\,dx $$
where $w(x)$ is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function which equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$. Letting $W(x)=\int_{0}^{x}w(t)\,dt$ we have that $0\leq W(x)\leq\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ for any $x\geq 0$. The first stationary point of $W(x)$ occurs at $x=\pi$. By invoking integration by parts it follows that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+n^2}=1+\int_{0}^{+\infty}W(x)e^{-x}\,dx\geq 1+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x(2\pi-x)}{4}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{\pi+1}{2}(1+e^{-2\pi}) $$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+n^2}\leq 1+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x(2\pi-x)}{4}e^{-x}\,dx +\frac{\pi^2}{4}\int_{\pi}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{\pi+1}{2}+\frac{1}{2e^\pi}, $$
hence
$$ \left|\frac{\pi+1}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{25}, $$
which trivially implies your inequality.